# ng-repeat v/s md-virtual-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-material

Difference between angular ng-repeat and angular material md-virtual-repeat?

When should i use one or another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ng-repeat` renders all elements in list, its less performant on large lists.

`md-virtual-repeat` renders list what is visible on viewport, it doesn't render all elements of list, when user scrolls in case of large lists it then seemlesly renders other elements, this way its performant and should be used when working with large lists.

Comment: Can we use a filter with md-virtual-repeat?

Comment: thank you so much, buddy. It was a great help indeed.

Answer (score 5):

Angular documentation tells it pretty clearly:

> Virtual repeat is a limited substitute for ng-repeat that renders only enough dom nodes to fill the container and recycling them as the user scrolls. Arrays, but not objects are supported for iteration. Track by, as alias, and (key, value) syntax are not supported.

[Source](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdVirtualRepeat)

Answer (score 2):

`md-virtual-repeat` is similar to `ng-repeat` but it is very useful when you want to load large amount of data.

Consider you have to load a 100,000 records. In this case if it is `ng-repeat` then it will load all the data initially. So the user may get frustrated while it is loading. If the user wants the first 50 rows of data only, `ng-repeat` forces him to wait until all 100,000 records load!

To avoid this in material we have `md-virtual-repeat`. It loads the next set of data when there is a demand for it (the user scrolls for more data)

Ultimately, the loading time is optimized if you use `md-virtual-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

> The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given loop variable is set to the current collection item, and $index is set to the item index or key.
> [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties)

`ng-repeat` loads the entire data set before rendering to the UI. It is extremely useful when dealing with a smaller list. To ensure that it is most effective it is advisable to use track by and or limit to in the `ng-repeat` expression. A great `md-data-table` example that uses `ng-repeat` is [Daniel Nagy's table](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table)

With a large list of records `ng-repeat` becomes very much slower. If it is slow the recommended usage is to switch to `md-virtual-repeat`

> md-virtual-repeat specifies an element to repeat using virtual scrolling.
> Virtual repeat is a limited substitute for ng-repeat that renders only enough DOM nodes to fill the container and recycling them as the user scrolls.
> [Source](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdVirtualRepeat)

`md-virtual-repeat` only loads the data on demand - the user scrolls. It loads the data much quicker when having a large result set. `md-virtual-repeat` becomes cumbersome when inserting it into a table.